# After setup.py, module must be explicitly imported from package

Tags: python, installation, distutils, setup.py

I've just made my first Python package with a setup script and am wondering if this behavior is normal. It's composed of one module containing a class I'd like to access. The project structure is like this:

```
.
|
+ -- __init__.py
+ -- setup.py
my_package
    |
    + __init__.py
    + my_class.py
```

`__init__.py` is always empty.

When I install it, this is the behavior I would expect:

```
>>> import my_package
>>> my_class.MyClass()
A new object is born!
```

Instead, I can only do that if I do this:

```
>>> from my_package import my_class
>>> my_class.MyClass()
A new object is born!
```

My package and my class file are named the same, if that's relevant. Is this a case of bad package design? I've found that I can get around the problem by putting `from my_class import *` in `__init__.py` but I hate using such statements, even if they stay in the import namespace.

Comment: If you import `my_package`, why do you expect `my_class` to magically appear?

Comment: You're right, I understand that the import has to be more explicit. I'm just not sure what best practice is in order to get `my_class` to magically appear ;)

Comment: This is not actually a packaging question, just an issue of familiarity with Python imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`import my_package` will import what is defined in `my_package/__init__.py`, so this behaviour is completely normal. You cannot use `my_class` since you don't have any reference to that module.

I don't know if your package design is *good* or *bad*, but if you want to use `MyClass` when you import `my_package`, just move this class to the script `my_package/__init__.py`.

Comment: What would be best practice in that case? If I use `from my_package import *` it's ugly, but at least it would stay in the namespace of `my_package`, so I'd be able to track down where it came from. Or is there a better way of going about it?

Comment: @DanielLee `from my_package.my_class import MyClass` and `from my_package import my_class` are both fine. In general, avoid import statements like `from my_package import *`. You can find more information in the [documentation FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-import-in-a-module) too.